# on hover event hide the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide the div 'sample' on hover event and need to show the div 'sample' on mouseout

```js
$('.secmenu').hover(function() {

  $('.sample').css('opacity', '0');
  if ($('.secmenu').mouseleave()) {
    $('.sample').css('opacity', '1');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="secmenu">click</a>
<div class="sample">
  hello div sample text content hello div sample text content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.secmenu').mouseenter(function() {//hide div on mouse enter
    $('.sample').hide();
}).mouseleave(function() {//show div on mouse leave
    $('.sample').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="secmenu">click</a>
<div class="sample">
  hello div sample text content hello div sample text content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in css. No need of jQuery:

```css
.secmenu:hover + .sample {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="secmenu">click</a>
<div class="sample">
  hello div sample text content hello div sample text content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide div on `hover` and show div on `mouseleave` event. You need to bind the `mouseleave` event not write it in `if` condition.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.secmenu').hover(function () {

        $('.sample').css('opacity', '0');

    });
    $('.secmenu').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.sample').css('opacity', '1');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('.secmenu').on('mouseenter',function() {
  $('.sample').css('opacity', '0');
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('.sample').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="secmenu">click</a>
<div class="sample">
  hello div sample text content hello div sample text content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `.sample` is immediate next sibling of `.secmneu` you don't need JavaScript or jQuery for this. You can do it with pure CSS.

```css
.sample {
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.secmenu:hover + .sample {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="secmenu">click</a>
<div class="sample">
  hello div sample text content hello div sample text content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer **enters and leaves** the elements.
>
> .hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )

So you can do it like this ([try it out](https://jsfiddle.net/jdhh7pqo/)):

```
$( '.secmenu' ).hover(
  function() {
    $('.sample').hide();
  },
  function() {
    $('.sample').show();
  }
);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```